# Importing a .sql file into mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a 500 mb .sql file sent to me by one of my clients. I downloaded MySQL Versio 8.0 and want to open this file in MySQL workbench. I tried opening the .sql file through MySQL workbench but it ended with errors and did not export all the tables, so I tried the following commands on MySQL 8.0 command line client.

Use database_name;

SOURCE filepath\filename.sql;

The .sql file is 500 mb. It contains just queries to create tables and insert values into the tables. Its been 4 hours and the import is still running, does this usually take this long? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Are you restoring the sql file to a local instance of MySQL or are you restoring it to a remote instance (aka over the Internet). If the answer is the later it may take awhile depending on a number of factors including the MySQL server hardware and your Internet connection.

Comment: @ThatGuyInIT to a local instance

Comment: `SOURCE` can only be used to import local files @ThatGuyInIT

Comment: mysql program import should be much faster something like   `mysql .... < file.sql`

Comment: @RaymondNijland I was about to do that but I dont know where to copy my .sql file so I used source

Comment: mysql program should also be able to import sql files annywhere on disk assuming the file permissions are corectly set

Comment: @RaymondNijland I am trying to execute the command from sql command line client as unable to use mysql command on windows command prompt

Comment: `SHOW PROCESSLIST` or the equivalent in the Workbench tool can tell you *roughly* how far it's gotten. If your server isn't tuned very well an import can take almost forever, but it's hard to know how long is normal if you haven't already restored it once before.

Comment: @RaymondNijland good catch

Comment: @KaranNeginhal You may want to take a look at this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20832/slow-mysql-database-import-with-mysqldump-and-use-source